# Java code for inserting data into a MySQL database gives an 'Error: No value specified for parameter 2' - how do I fix it?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on my internal assessment for [IB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Baccalaureate) for computer science, and I have the snippet of code that basically is supposed to insert a row within a subjects table that contains both a subject name, and the amount of events under such subject.

It is able to see the amount of events by referencing another separate table called 'Events' within the database, and will put in the amount of events that will have the name of the subject inserted within.

However, the error I am getting is:

> Error: No value specified for parameter 2

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Here's the code to work with:

```
private void insertSubject_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String command = evt.getActionCommand();

    String dbName = "ScheduleManagementDB";
    String tableName = "Subjects";
    String[] columnNames =
    {
        "Subject", "EventAmount"
    };
    String dbQuery = "INSERT INTO Subjects VALUES(?,?)";

    JavaMySQL_DB objDb = new JavaMySQL_DB(dbName);
    Connection myDbConn = objDb.getDbConn();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try
    {
        ps = myDbConn.prepareStatement(dbQuery);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.print("error");
    }
    String Subject;
    int EventAmount;

    Subject = insertSubject_Field.getText();

    String getCountQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Events WHERE SubjectE = ?";
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        ps.setString(1, Subject);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        PreparedStatement getCountPs = myDbConn.prepareStatement(getCountQuery);
        getCountPs.setString(1, Subject);
        ResultSet rs = getCountPs.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next())
        {
            count = rs.getInt(1);
        }

        ps.setInt(2, count);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Data Inserted");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I tried not using a result set either as I thought that the getCountQuery statement would work anyway, as I just need a value, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can't invoke the `PreparedStatement` `ps` until you *bind* **both** parameters. You currently bind the first one, then attempt to call execute update and then attempt to load the second value by calling another `PreparedStatement`. Perform that first. Also, you currently leak your `Connection`, `Statement`(s) and `ResultSet`(s). Either close them yourself, or use a `try-with-Resources`. Something like

```
private void insertSubject_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String command = evt.getActionCommand();
    String dbName = "ScheduleManagementDB";
    String tableName = "Subjects";
    String[] columnNames = { "Subject", "EventAmount" };
    String dbQuery = "INSERT INTO Subjects VALUES(?,?)";
    String getCountQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Events WHERE SubjectE = ?";

    JavaMySQL_DB objDb = new JavaMySQL_DB(dbName);

    String Subject = insertSubject_Field.getText();
    int count = 0;
    try (Connection myDbConn = objDb.getDbConn()) {
        try (PreparedStatement getCountPs = myDbConn
                    .prepareStatement(getCountQuery)) {
            getCountPs.setString(1, Subject);
            try (ResultSet rs = getCountPs.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    count = rs.getInt(1);
                }
            }
        }
        try (PreparedStatement ps = myDbConn.prepareStatement(dbQuery)) {
            ps.setString(1, Subject);
            ps.setInt(2, count);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Data Inserted");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```